# Using the fullcalendar function in R using columns from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, fullcalendar, shinydashboard

I have been using the following structure as an example to follow:

```
output$test <- renderFullcalendar({ 
fullcalendar(events = data.frame(title = c("ex1","ex2","ex3"),
      start = c("2020-01-15","2020-02-14","2019-12-07"), 
      color = c("red","green","red") #"red", "orange")
```

I have a dataframe with a column for title, start and color. I want to be able to use the columns of that dataframe for the choices in the events data.frame below. In other words, this is the code that I have written that is not working:

```
output$test <- renderFullcalendar({
      data1 <- calendar_subset() #Data.frame that is filtered based on user input
      col1 <- select(data1,cat(paste(shQuote(CAL_DATE2), collapse = ", ")))
      billnum <- select(data1,cat(paste(shQuote(Billing_Num),collapse = ", ")))
      colll <- select(data1,cat(paste(shQuote(color),collapse = ", ")))
   fullcalendar(events = data.frame(
      title = c(billnum),
      start = c(col1),
      color = c(colll)
           ))
})
```

When running this code, the calendar appears in the dashboard; however, none of the events are shown and no error is returned.

The full code is below:

```
outputDir <- "responses"

#Define the fields we want to save from the form **** ADD INFO ALREADY THERE AFTER THIS 
#fields <- c("UW_Name", "UWselect", "UW_Selected_Smod", "UW_Pricing_Justification")

getTotal <- function(data,index){

  if(index < 1 || index > ncol(data)){
    return("")
  }
  col <- data[,index]
  col <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(col))
  if(all(is.na(col))){
    return("")
  }
  sum(col)
}

saveData <- function(input){
  # Save the input data 
  data <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=0))
  for (x in fields) {
    var <- input[[x]]
    if(length(var) > 1) {
      #handles lists from checkboxGroup and multiple Select 
      data[[x]] <- list(var)
    } else{
      #all other data types
      data[[x]] <- var
    }
  }

  data$submit_time <- date()

  #Create a unique file name
  fileName <- sprintf(
    "%s_%s.rds",
    as.integer(Sys.time()),
    digest::digest(data)
  )


  #Write the file to the local system
  saveRDS(
    object = data,
    file = file.path(outputDir,fileName)
  )

}

loadData <- function(){
  #read all the files into a list
  files <- list.files(outputDir, full.names =TRUE)

  if (length(files) == 0){ 
    #create empty data frame with correct columns
    field_list <- c(fields, "submit_time")
    data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(field_list), nrow =0))
    names(data) <- field_list
  } else {
    data <- lapply(files, function(x) readRDS(x))  

    #Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
    data<- do.call(rbind, data)
  }
  data 
}

# deleteData <- function() {
#   #Read all the files into a list
#   files <- list.files(outputDir,full.names=TRUE)
#   
#   lapply(files, file.remove)
# }

resetForm <- function(session) {
  #reset values
  updateNumericInput(session, "UW_Selected_Smod", value=0)
  updateTextAreaInput(session, "UW_Pricing_Justification", value = "")
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Active Contracts Mod"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    jqui_draggable(
      absolutePanel(id="yerrr",
        right=160, top=110, width = 250, 
        draggable = TRUE, 
        wellPanel(
      helpText("Please enter the information below: "),
      uiOutput("nullSelection"),
      uiOutput("firstSelection"),
      uiOutput("secondSelection")),
    style = "opacity:0.88"), 
  option=list(cancel = ".selectize-control")),
  useShinyjs(),
    tags$style(HTML(".box-header{background:#d2d2d2; color:#d83000; text-align:center;}")),
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.info-box {min-height: 45px;} .info-box-icon {height: 45px; line-height: 45px;} .info-box-content {padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;}'))),
    shinyUI <- fluidPage(


      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          id = 'dataset',
          tabPanel("General Contract Information",box(width = '100%', 
title = "General Information", infoBoxOutput("CName", width=12),
                   fluidRow(column(width=5, 
                   infoBoxOutput("box1",width=8),
                   infoBoxOutput("box2",width=8),
                   infoBoxOutput("box3",width=8)),
                   column(width=5,
                          infoBoxOutput("box4",width=8),
                          infoBoxOutput("box5",width=8),
                          infoBoxOutput("box6",width=8)))),
                   box(width = "60%", title = "Contact Information", 
                    fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("Cbox1",width=3),
                             infoBoxOutput("Cbox2",width=3),
                             infoBoxOutput("Cbox3",width=6)))),
          tabPanel("Mods",box(width='100%',
                              infoBoxOutput("Mbox1",width = 4),
                              infoBoxOutput("Mbox2",width = 4),
                              infoBoxOutput("Mbox3",width = 4),
                              infoBoxOutput("Mbox4",width = 4),
                              infoBoxOutput("Mbox5",width = 4)
                              )),
          tabPanel("Payment History",
               column(12,box(width='100%', title = textOutput("gtitle"), radioButtons("filter", "Payment History Filter:",
                                                            list("Received/Billed","Billed/Funded","Received/Funded")),

gaugeOutput("gauge"),  
                   br(), box(width = '100%', title = "Detailed Billing History",
                   tableOutput("AR_Table"))))),
          tabPanel("Billing Schedule History", box(width='100%', title = textOutput("BSH"),  
                   fullcalendarOutput("test",width = "100%", height = "800px"))),
                  ")),column(width=6,br(),infoBoxOutput("boxPI",width=12),

        ))))
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

  # Hide the general information until a Master Code is selected from the dropdown

  observeEvent(input$MCC,  {
    if (input$MCC == ""){
      hide(id="CName")
      hide(id="box1")
      hide(id="box2")
      hide(id="box3")
      hide(id="box4")
      hide(id="box5")
      hide(id="box6")
      hide(id="Cbox1")
      hide(id="Cbox2")
      hide(id="Cbox3")
    }
    else{
      show(id="CName")
      show(id="box1")
      show(id="box2")
      show(id="box3")
      show(id="box4")
      show(id="box5")
      show(id="box6")
      show(id="Cbox1")
      show(id="Cbox2")
      show(id="Cbox3")
      }
  })

  #When the Submit Button is clicked, save the form data
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    saveData(input)
    resetForm(session)
  })

  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    resetForm(session)
  })

  observeEvent(input$dataset,{
    if(input$dataset == "Input History" || input$dataset == "Input Form"){
      hide(id ="yerrr")
    }
    else{show(id="yerrr")}
  })



  ###########
  # OUTPUTS #
  ###########

  # Tracking current tab 
  output$currenttab <- renderText({
    input$dataset
  })


  #Show the previous responses in a reactive table
  output$responses <- renderDataTable({
    #update with current response when Submit or Delete are clicked
    input$submit
    input$delete


    loadData()
  })

  output$AR_Table <- renderTable(df3_subset(), spacing=c("xs"), align = NULL)
  output$Tabble <- renderTable(calendar_subset(), spacing=c("xs"), align = NULL)


  #Downloadable csv of selected dataset
   output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "data.csv",
     content = function(file) {
      write.csv(loadData(),file,row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
    }
  )


  #*#* Read CSV and take dynamic user input 

  # Reading csv to dataframe variable
  CMF <- read.csv(here("CMF_static.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
  ARHR <- read.csv(here("AR_History.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # Draggable UI box 
  output$nullSelection <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "MCC","Main Charge Code",
                choices = c("",paste0(sort((unique(CMF$Filter1)))))
    )
  })

  output$firstSelection <- renderUI ({
    LVL2 <- CMF[CMF$Filter1 == input$MCC,]


    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MC != ''",
                     selectizeInput(inputId = "FCC", "Full Charge Code",
                             choices = 
 c("",paste0(sort(unique(LVL2$Filter2)))))
    )
  })

  #*#* Variable Names for CMF_Static

  Contract_NO <- c(CMF$ContractNO)
  MCC <- c(CMF$Filter1)
  FCC <- c(CMF$Filter2)
  Contract_Name <- c(CMF$Contract_or_Task_Name)
  Account_Type <- c(CMF$Account_Type)
  PM <-c(CMF$Project_Manager)
  Active <- c(CMF$Active)
  Contract_Type <- c(CMF$Contract_Type)
  Client <- c(CMF$Client)
  PCN <- c(CMF$Prime_Contract_Number)
  OCN <- c(CMF$Other_Contract_Number)
  Contact <- c(CMF$Contact)
  Phone <- c(CMF$Phone)
  BillAddress <- c(CMF$Billing_Address1)
  BillAddress2 <- c(CMF$Billing_Address_2)
  BillAddress3 <- c(CMF$Billing_Address_3)
  OG_Contract_Cost <- c(CMF$Original_Contract_Cost)
  OG_Fee_Amount <- c(CMF$Original_Fee_Amount)
  OG_Total_Amount <- c(CMF$Original_Total_Value)
  OG_Start_Date <- c(CMF$Original_Starting_Date)
  OG_End_Date <- c(CMF$Original_Ending_Date)
  MCCA <- c(CMF$Modifications_Contract_Cost_Amount)
  MFA <- c(CMF$Modifications_Fee_Amount)
  MTV <- c(CMF$Modifications_Total_Value)
  MSD <- c(CMF$Modifications_Starting_Date)
  MED <- c(CMF$Modifications_Ending_Date)
  TCC_O_M <- c(CMF$Total_Contract_Cost_Original_and_Modifications)
  TFA_O_M <- c(CMF$Total_Fee_Amount_Original_and_Modifications)
  TV_O_M <- c(CMF$Total_Value_Original_and_Modifications)
  FCCosts <- c(CMF$Funded_Contract_Costs)
  FFA <- c(CMF$Funded_Fee_Amount)
  FTV <- c(CMF$Funded_Total_Value)
  RA <- c(CMF$Revenue_Adjustment)
  RB <- c(CMF$Revenue_Basis)
  CCFP <- c(CMF$Current_Contract_Fee_Percentage)

  # Variables for ARHR 
  Account_Num <- c(ARHR$Filter3)
  Account_Num_Spec <- c(ARHR$Filter4)
  Account_Name <- c(ARHR$ACCOUNT_NAME)
  Billing_Num <- c(ARHR$BILL_NO)
  Date <- c(ARHR$DATE)
  Tran_Type <- c(ARHR$TRANSACTION_TYPE)
  Transaction_Amt <- c(ARHR$TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)
  Transaction_Amt2 <- c(ARHR$TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)
  CAL_DATE <- c(ARHR$CAL_DATE)
  color <- c(ARHR$color)
  CAL_DATE2 <- (ARHR$CAL_DATE2)

  ########## DATAFRAMES ############

  # #Data Table on General Contract Information tab / Mods information tab
  df <- data.frame(MCC, FCC,Contract_Type,PCN,OCN,OG_Start_Date,OG_End_Date,PM,Contract_Name,Contact,Phone,BillAddress,BillAddress2,BillAddress3,MCCA,MFA,MTV,MSD,MED,TCC_O_M) 
  df_subset <- reactive({
    n01 <- input$MCC
    n02 <- input$FCC

    c <- subset(df, MCC == n01 & FCC == n02)

   return(c)
  })

  # #Progress Filter for Gauge 
  df2 <-data.frame(Account_Num,Account_Num_Spec,Account_Name,Billing_Num,Date,Tran_Type,Transaction_Amt2)
  df2_subset <- reactive({
    m1 <- input$MCC
    m2 <- input$FCC
    m3 <- input$filter

    if(m3 == "Billed/Funded"){
      m3a <- "Bill"
      c2 <- subset(df2, Account_Num == m1 & Account_Num_Spec == m2 & Tran_Type == m3a)

    }
    else if(m3 == "Received/Funded"){
      m3a <- "Bill"
      c2 <- subset(df2, Account_Num == m1 & Account_Num_Spec == m2 & Tran_Type == m3a)

    }
    else{
      m3a <- "Receipt"
      c2 <- subset(df2, Account_Num == m1 & Account_Num_Spec == m2 & Tran_Type == m3a)
    }


    return(c2)
  })

  # #Total Filter for Gauge (Received/Billed) 
df2a <- 

data.frame(Account_Num,Account_Num_Spec,Account_Name,Billing_Num,Date,Tran_Type,Transaction_Amt2)
  df2a_subset <- reactive({
    m1a <- input$MCC
    m2a <- input$FCC
    m3a <- input$filter
    m3aa <- "Bill"
    c2a <- subset(df2a, Account_Num == m1a & Account_Num_Spec == m2a & Tran_Type == m3aa)

    return(c2a)
  })

  # #Data Table on Payment History Tab
  df3 <-data.frame(Account_Num,Account_Num_Spec,Account_Name,Billing_Num,Date,Tran_Type,Transaction_Amt2) 
  df3_subset <- reactive({
    n1 <- input$MCC
    n2 <- input$FCC
    n3 <- input$filter

    if(n3 == "Received/Billed"){
      n3a <- "Combined"
      c3 <- subset(df3, Account_Num == n1 & Account_Num_Spec == n2 & Tran_Type != n3a)
    }
    else if(n3 == "Billed/Funded"){
      n3a <- "Bill"
      c3 <- subset(df3, Account_Num == n1 & Account_Num_Spec == n2 & Tran_Type == n3a)
    }
    else{
      n3a <- "Receipt"
      c3 <- subset(df3, Account_Num == n1 & Account_Num_Spec == n2 & Tran_Type == n3a)
    }

    return(c3)
  })

  # #Calendar Billing History (Billed)
  calendar <- data.frame(Account_Num,Account_Num_Spec,Account_Name,Billing_Num,Date,Tran_Type,Transaction_Amt2,CAL_DATE,color,CAL_DATE2)
  calendar_subset <- reactive({
    o1 <- input$MCC
    o2 <- input$FCC

    c4 <- subset(calendar, Account_Num == o1 & Account_Num_Spec == o2, Tran_Type == "Bill")

    return(c4)
  })

  cal1 <- data.frame(CAL_DATE)
  cal1_subset <- reactive({
    data1 <- calendar_subset()
    col1 <- as.list(select(data1,str(CAL_DATE)))
    len <- length(data1)
    #data1a <- data1[data1 < len,7]
    thecolor <- vector()
    count <- 0
    while(count < len){
      append(thecolor,"red")
      count <- count+1
    }

     B_data <- data.frame(start = c(col1),
                         end = c(col1),
                         color = c(thecolor))
    return(B_data)
  })



  # data.frame(start = c("2017-03-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-03-15"),
  #              end = c("2017-03-02", "2017-03-04", "2017-03-18"),
  #              color = c("red", "blue", "green"))


  # #Calendar Billing History (Scheduled)


  # Contract Type Box
  CName <- data.frame(Contract_Name)
  cn_subset <- reactive({
    a <- df_subset()
    a1 <- a[1,9]
    a2 <- h1(a1)
    return(a2)
  })

  output$CName <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Contract Name", 
value=cn_subset(),color = "black", icon = icon("bookmark"),fill = TRUE)))


  # Contract Type Box
  box1 <- data.frame(Contract_Type)
  box1_subset <- reactive({
    A <- df_subset()
    A1 <- A[1,3]
    return(A1)
  })

  output$box1 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Contract Type", 
value=box1_subset(), color = "light-blue", icon = icon("info-circle"),fill = TRUE)))

  # # Prime Contract # Box
  box2 <- data.frame(PCN)
  box2_subset <- reactive({
    B <- df_subset()
    B1 <- B[1,4]
    return(B1)
  })

  output$box2 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Prime Contract #", 
value=box2_subset(), color = "light-blue", icon = icon("book"), fill = TRUE)))

  # PO #
  box3 <- data.frame(OCN)
  box3_subset <- reactive({
    C <- df_subset()
    C1 <- C[1,5]
    return(C1)
  })

  output$box3 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("PO Number", value=box3_subset(), 
color = "light-blue", icon = icon("book"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Project Manager
  box4 <- data.frame(PM)
  box4_subset <- reactive({
    D <- df_subset()
    D1 <- D[1,8]
    return(D1)
  })

  output$box4 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Project Manager", value=box4_subset(), color = "light-blue", icon = icon("address-card"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Project Manager
  box5 <- data.frame(OG_Start_Date)
  box5_subset <- reactive({
    E <- df_subset()
    E1 <- E[1,6]
    return(E1)
  })

  output$box5 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Original Start Date",     value=box5_subset(), color = "light-blue", icon = icon("calendar"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Project Manager
  box6 <- data.frame(OG_End_Date)
  box6_subset <- reactive({
    F <- df_subset()
    F1 <- F[1,7]
    return(F1)
  })

  output$box6 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Original End Date", value=box6_subset(), color = "light-blue", icon = icon("calendar"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Contact Name 
  Cbox1 <- data.frame(Contact)
  Cbox1_subset <- reactive({
    G <- df_subset()
    G1 <- G[1,10]
    return(G1)
  })

  output$Cbox1 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Contact Name", value=Cbox1_subset(), color = "lime", icon = icon("address-card"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Phone Number 
  Cbox2 <- data.frame(Phone)
  Cbox2_subset <- reactive({
    H <- df_subset()
    H1 <- H[11]
    return(H1)
  })

  output$Cbox2 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Phone #", value=Cbox2_subset(),     color = "lime", icon = icon("phone"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Billing address
  Cbox3 <- data.frame(BillAddress)
  Cbox3_subset <- reactive({
    I <- df_subset()
    I1 <- I[1,12] 
    I2 <- I[1,13]
    I3 <- I[1,14]
    I4 <- HTML(paste(I1,HTML("<br/>"),I2,HTML("<br/>"),I3))
    return(I4)
  })

  output$Cbox3 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Billing Address", value=Cbox3_subset(), color = "lime", icon = icon("map-pin"), fill = TRUE)))


  # Contract Cost Modification
  Mbox1 <- data.frame(MCCA)
  Mbox1_subset <- reactive({
    J <- df_subset()
    J1 <- paste("$ ",accounting(J[1,15])) 
    return(J1)
  })

  output$Mbox1 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Contract Cost Mod", value=Mbox1_subset(), color = "yellow", icon = icon("exchange"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Fee Amount Modification
  Mbox2 <- data.frame(MFA)
  Mbox2_subset <- reactive({
    K <- df_subset()
    K1 <- paste("$ ",accounting(K[1,16]))
    return(K1)
  })

  output$Mbox2 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Fee Amount Mod", value=Mbox2_subset(), color = "yellow", icon = icon("exchange"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Total Value Modification
  Mbox3 <- data.frame(MTV)
  Mbox3_subset <- reactive({
    L <- df_subset()
    L1 <- paste("$ ",accounting(L[1,17]))
    return(L1)
  })

  output$Mbox3 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Total Value Mod", value=Mbox3_subset(), color = "yellow", icon = icon("exchange"), fill = TRUE)))

  # Start Date Modification
  Mbox4 <- data.frame(MSD)
  Mbox4_subset <- reactive({
    M <- df_subset()
    M1 <- M[1,18] 
    return(M1)
  })

  output$Mbox4 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("Start Date Mod", value=Mbox4_subset(), color = "yellow", icon = icon("exchange"), fill = TRUE)))

  # End Date Modification
  Mbox5 <- data.frame(MED)
  Mbox5_subset <- reactive({
    N <- df_subset()
    N1 <- N[1,19] 
    return(N1)
  })


  output$Mbox5 <- renderInfoBox((infoBox("End Date Mod",     value=Mbox5_subset(), color = "yellow", icon = icon("exchange"), fill = TRUE)))# Contract Cost Modification

  # Gauge Control MAX 
  Gbox1 <- data.frame(TCC_O_M)
  Gbox1_subset <- reactive({
    O <- df_subset()
    O1 <- O[1,20]
    return(O1)
  })

  Total <- reactive({
    getTotal(df2_subset(),7)
  })

  # Gauge Billed Amount
  Gbox2 <- data.frame(Transaction_Amt)
  Gbox2_subset <- reactive({
    P <- df2a_subset()
    P1 <- P[,7]
    #P2 <- suppressWarnings(unlist(as.numeric(P1)))
    P3 <- as.numeric(sum(P1))
    return(P3)
  })



  #Gauge title 
  thegtitle <- reactive({

      titlepg <- input$filter
      if(titlepg == "Received/Billed"){
        tpage <- "Payments Received of Total Billed"
      }
      else if(titlepg == "Billed/Funded"){
        tpage <- "Total Billed of Total Funded"
      }
      else{
        tpage <- "Payments Received of Total Funded"
      }

      thetitle <- paste0(tpage)

    return(thetitle)
  })

  output$gtitle <- renderText({thegtitle()})


  # GAUGE
  output$gauge <- renderGauge({
    #validate(
      #need(input$ED, "Please fill each of the drop-down lists to the right in order to access the Risk Score")
    #)
    decide <- input$filter

    if(decide == "Received/Billed"){
      hold <- Gbox2_subset()
      themax <- Gbox2_subset()    
        }
    else{
      hold <- Gbox1_subset()
      themax <- Gbox1_subset()
        }

    one_third <- (hold/3)
    two_third <- (hold/3)*2
    numerator <- Total()
    gauge(numerator, #quin_subset()$Qtiles,
          min = 0,
          max = themax,
          sectors = gaugeSectors(success = c(two_third,hold),
                                 warning = c(one_third,two_third),
                                 danger = c(0,one_third)))
  })

  # Billing Schedule History Title
  BSH_title <- reactive({
    pull <- input$MCC
    pull2 <- input$FCC

    if(pull2 == "Combined"){
      thepull <- paste0(pull, " Combined")
    }
    else{
      thepull <- paste0(pull2)
    }

    return(thepull)
  })

  output$BSH <- renderText({BSH_title()})


  # CALENDAR

  output$test <- renderFullcalendar({
      data1 <- calendar_subset()
      col1 <- select(data1,cat(paste(shQuote(CAL_DATE2), collapse = ",     ")))
      billnum <- select(data1,cat(paste(shQuote(Billing_Num),collapse = ", 
")))
          colll <- select(data1,cat(paste(shQuote(color),collapse = ",     ")))
          fullcalendar(events = data.frame(
            #title = c("ex1","ex2","ex3"),
            #start = c("2020-01-15","2020-02-14","2019-12-07"),     #Sys.Date() + 0:1,
            #color = c("red","green","red"))) #"red", "orange")
            title = c(billnum),
            start = c(col1), #Sys.Date() + 0:1,
            end = c(col1),
            color = c(colll)))
      })





    } #end
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thoughts?

Please let me know if I need to make any clarifications/specifications with my question. Thanks.

Comment: There is a problem in the brackets of the function it should end like that color = c(colll)})

Comment: I just updated the code, I did not show it correctly- I left out the "fullcalendar(events = data.fame(" portion. Therefore I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your shiny code and example data to reproduce?

Comment: I have added the full code.